# Creating a list of all directory

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a list of all directories and their sub-directories in a given path in visual studio 2012.

It's a very long time since I've been in touch with visual basic. I hope somebody can show a simple way for this task.

Any kind of help is much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the System.IO namespace

```
 Directory.GetDirectories(string, string, SearchOptions)
```

A good example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314.aspx)

```
 Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
 Console.WriteLine("The number of directories starting with p is {0}.", dirs.Length)
 Dim dir As String 
 For Each dir In dirs
    Console.WriteLine(dir)
 Next 
 Catch e As Exception
      Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString())
 End Try
```

However keep in mind that some directories could have particular access permissions and your code could fail with an IOException. (That's particularly true for the system directories)

Another option is through the use of [Directory.EnumerateDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383462.aspx) that is preferable when you work with many directories and you don't need to have the string array with names filled.

EnumerateDirectories start immediately without waiting to filling the array and is very useful in situation where your code loops over the enumeration

```
  For Each dirName in Directory.EnumerateDirectories("C:\", "p*", SearchOptions.AllDirectories)
     ..... do something with the directory here ....
  Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim path as string ="c:\DirectoryTest"

Dim result = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Comment: It may sound a dumb question, but how can I use the result variable. is it an array?

Comment: @Tera, I updated my question, you get it as IEnumerable string, best is using a list

Comment: in the Dim DirList As List(of string)......I receive the following error.
Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

Answer (score 0):

This recursive method will get all directories & its sub-directories from a given path:

**Option 1#**

```
 Public Shared Sub ProcessDirectory(ByVal targetDirectory As String)
        Dim subdirectoryEntries As String() = 
                  Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory)
        ' Recurse into subdirectories of this directory. 
        Dim subdirectory As String 
        For Each subdirectory In subdirectoryEntries
            ProcessDirectory(subdirectory)
        Next subdirectory

    End Sub
```

**Option 2#**

```
Module Module1

        Sub Main()
            Try 
                Dim dirPath As String = "c:\\myDirctory" 

                Dim dirs As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dirPath))

                For Each folder In dirs
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", folder.Substring(folder.LastIndexOf("\") + 1))
                Next
                Console.WriteLine("{0} directories found.", dirs.Count)
            Catch UAEx As UnauthorizedAccessException
                Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message)
            Catch PathEx As PathTooLongException
                Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message)
            End Try 

        End Sub 
    End Module
```

You can refer MSDN for further details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2